# I lost an object i have been working on for hours, how do i get it back?

Tags: camera

I have been working on a doughnut almost all day, and when I started making a sprinkle, I suddenly lost track of the doughnut, I've been pressing all sorts of buttons so I'm not sure what I did, but it is nowhere to be found.

I can see it up in the top right but when I click on the name nothing happens.  I'm very new to blender.

Comment: With the name highlighted in the top right (click on it so it's "selected") move your mouse pointer back into the viewport area and press the decimal (.) on the Numpad. This should center the camera back on your object if it's visible. If it's hidden, there should be a small "smile shaped line" instead of an eyeball next to it's name. However, if it's "gone" it's not a total loss - one of the best ways to do the donut tutorial is to go until you make a mistake and then _start over from the beginning_. The repetition makes you more familiar with (and much faster at) blender's features quickly.

Comment: Make sure you are not in local view. Go to View > Local View > Toggle Local View or shortcut numpad / (might depend on the localization of your keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

Please press <kbd>⌥ Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to unhide, or check if you accidentally moved it into another layer, or switch between *object* and *edit* modes.